# Integration Test for methods with no returning value in Java

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, integration-testing

I am trying to build an integration test method in Java, but there are some service methods that have no returning value (void). So, in this scene, normally I would create a record and then retrieve this record using the id of created record. However, as there is no returned value, how can I write integration test for example such a kind of service method? Is that possible?

```
public void saveProperties(final Request request, final UUID productUuid) {
    repository.saveProduct(request, productUuid);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to build an integration test for this method?

Comment: 'So, in this scene, normally I would create a record and then retrieve this record using the id of created record.' - how is this scenario different? Isn't `productUuid` sth you could retrieve the product by?

Comment: @crizzis When I call `saveProperties` in the test method, it does not return anything. So, how can I use `productUuid`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You call `saveProperties` with certain parameters. `productUuid` is one of them. Can't you then use the same `productUuid` you used for the method call to retrieve the product (`repository.findByProductUuid()`, `entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.uuid = :uuid").getSingleResult()` or whatever other method you have available) to retrieve the product and check whether it has been correctly saved?

Comment: Alternatively, there's nothing stopping you to return the id of the created/updated product for testing purposes. You can ignore it in your production code and make use of it in the test code

Comment: You right, but assume that the service methods are fix and I should not update them. I just need to use them in my test method. I think in this case the only thing I can do is **calling another method by passing a proper value in order to retrieve the saved entity**. Is that true? I also thought it but nor was sure and wanted to know if there is another proper way.

Comment: If you mean one should use one service method to save the value and another to retrieve it, then it doesn't make much sense. Let's say creating and retrieving a product are two separate user stories, how do you write the test for the first one to be implemented? Also, the scope of you test grows: now, the test breaks when either method fails, so it's not really testing just the `saveProperties` method

Comment: Why do not you post an example code instead of just adding comment? As I am beginner, it would be much more clean for me :)

Comment: you should make a clear distinction of what you want to test. a real integration test, and thus really inserting into a DB in memory for example (I assume `repository` is a spring jpa-repository). And the other one is a `mock` test, when you assert that calling `saveProperties` with the two arguments is going to _actually_ call your `repository.saveProduct`. These are very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually verify the service method was called or not using Mockito.verify.

Sample usage:

```
Mockito.verify(mockedObject, Mockito.times(1)).saveProduct(any(Request.class), any(UUID.class));
```

This will validate that the saveProduct was called on your mocked object.